# Titanium save files from stream

Tags: file, soap, titanium, base64, titanium-mobile

I have a `streamer` from server(SOAP) with different type of files, and i what seve it in physical storage.
I try this code but i only create file with my string.

```
api.getFile(function(fileString) {

        var original = 'Appcelerator';
        var decoded = Ti.Utils.base64decode(fileString);

        var Settings = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.tempDirectory, 'Settings');
        var newFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Settings.nativePath, 'Settings.pdf');
        newFile.createFile(decoded);
      // Ti.API.info('newfile: '+newFile.read());    
    }); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one..

```
 var original = 'Appcelerator';
 var decoded = Ti.Utils.base64decode(fileString);

 var Settings = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.tempDirectory, 'Settings');
 Settings.createDirectory();
 var newFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Settings.nativePath, 'Settings.pdf');
 newFile.write(decoded);
```